# Components do not save in specific dynamic placeholder

Tags: sxa, dynamic-placeholder

We are using sitecore 8.2 and recently added SXA sites. The existing site has a dynamic placeholder setting `section-content*`, which stopped working after we added SXA sites. When I looked for "section-content" in the website folder, I see some placeholders `@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("section-content")` added as part of SXA installation. I'm guessing there is a name conflict and that's the reason components do not save on this placeholder in the existing site. If I decide to rename the SXA PH, I don't understand the impact it might have. I need your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: This could be an implementation conflict.. what did you use for the dynamic placeholders in the existing site? It might be not compatible with SXA.

Comment: Pipeline setting before adding SXA in the exiting site:

<getPlaceholderRenderings>
        <processor  type="Hub.Website.Pipelines.GetDynamicAllowedRenderings, Hub.Website"
                    patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPlaceholderRenderings.GetAllowedRenderings, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
      </getPlaceholderRenderings>

Comment: As part of SXA implementation, code replaced the existing value with :
```<getPlaceholderRenderings>
        <processor  type="Hub.Website.Pipelines.GetDynamicAllowedRenderings, Hub.Website"
                    patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.XA.Foundation.DynamicPlaceholders.Pipelines.GetPlaceholderRenderings.ReplaceWildcardPlaceholderKey, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.DynamicPlaceholders']"/>
      </getPlaceholderRenderings>```